# Files in $ZSH_CUSTOM not loaded by oh-my-zsh

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am setting up ZSH with oh-my-zsh, and I want to preserve my `.bashrc` and `.bash_aliases` configurations.

From `~/.zshrc` I read that:

> Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh users are encouraged to
>   define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.

In the `$ZSH_CUSTOM` folder I find an `example.zsh` file that says:

> You can put files here to add functionality separated per file, which
>   will be ignored by git.
>   Files on the custom/ directory will be automatically loaded by the init
>   script, in alphabetical order.

Sounds great! Let's copy my bash files in there.

**BUT** it's not working! If I try one of my aliases I get:

> zsh: command not found

I tried removing the dot from the files' names but no change.

What's happening?

(If I source the files manually it works.)

Comment: Why not just put the aliases in `~/.zshrc` and skip the oh-my-zsh baggage?

Comment: Are you using oh-my-zsh or not? `ZSH_CUSTOM` is an oh-my-zsh thing.

Comment: @Gilles yes I am using oh-my-zsh, will edit to clarify.

Comment: @thrig that's what I'm doing right now but I'd prefer to do it the way it is intended.

Comment: Did you add the `.zsh` extension to your files?

Comment: If we all think like you @thrig, we would still move with horses and ass animals ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Files you create in `$ZSH_CUSTOM` need to have a file extension of `.zsh`, according to [the documentation](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Customization):

> oh-my-zsh's internals are defined in its lib directory. To change them, just create a file inside the custom directory (its name doesn't matter, as long as it has a .zsh ending)

If you just copied `.bashrc` and `.bash_aliases` into it, oh-my-zsh will therefore ignore them.

Comment: Going one step further: The diff between git.zsh and plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh in custom is that the latter has to be mentioned in the plugins list in .zshrc and goes in accordance with the plugins residing in /ohmyzsh.